# Accesing variables in ascx.cs to use them in .ascx webpart

Tags: c#, variables, sharepoint, ascx

I have a variable declared in "Mapas.ascx.cs" and I want to use it at "Mapas.ascx", but I don't know how to do it. (I'm using sharepoint2013)

My variable was declared like that:

```
    public string apiKey, direccion;
```

And the code where I want to use it is that:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:"DIRECCIONVARIABLE"&key="APIKEYVARIABLE" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Anyone can helps me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Define them as `public static`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Then provide your tried code.

Comment: I mean, I put a public static string at apiKey declaration and then I write "apiKey" on the .ascx file, and it said that apiKey doesn't exists in the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want call method or property in `.ascx` design code, you should define them as `public static`,

```
public static string ApiKey
{
    get
    {
        return "Name";
    }
}
public static string DoSomething()
{
    //Code here
    return "What you expected";
}
```

then in `aspx` design code:

```
 <span><%= yourClassName.DoSomething()%> </span>
 <span><%= YourClassName.ApiKey %> </span>
```

**UPDATE:**
For example you have something like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ClassName.ascx.cs" Inherits="YourNameSpace.X.Z.ClassName" %>
```

in your `ascx` design code in top of the page , so if you can't access them by `ClassName.ApiKey` then write the namespace like `YourNameSpace.X.Z.ClassName`.

Rebuilt your solution also.

Comment: I cannot see my class name when I do <span><%MyClassName%></span>

Comment: `yourClassName` used to clear you that you should type the class name that static stuff defined in it.

Comment: I know, I mean that I put my class name, but it said that it doesn't exist

Comment: You misunderstood my comment, try `Mapas.Name` instead, You don't have `className` in your project.

Comment: I know I don't have className in my project. I mean that I write Mapas.Name and it said to me that the Mapas does not exists in the current context...

Comment: I have that: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mapas.ascx.cs" Inherits="Ntasys.SharePoint.Mapas" %> it is not the same?

Comment: @Imrik, then try `<%= Ntasys.SharePoint.Mapas.ApiKey%>`

Comment: now I have to know if it works, but that is another question. thanks!

Comment: @Imrik, You are welcome, for new question make new one.